# How do I translate text in .java source files?

Tags: java, servlets, internationalization, translation

I have an enum like this

```
public enum CheckboxFeature {

    Option1(" choose this"),
    Option2(" or this"),
    Option3(" maybe this"),
    Option4(" lastly this");

    @Getter
    private final String text;

    public static CheckboxFeature fromName(String v) {
        for (CheckboxFeature c: CheckboxFeature.values()) {
            if (c.name().equalsIgnoreCase(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }
}
```

This shows the four options as checkboxes in the web view

```
<form:checkboxes items="${features}" path="enabledFeatures" itemLabel="text" delimiter="<br/>"/>
```

How can I translate these options? I use fmt:message for the rest of the translations in the web view.

I have tried

```
Option1(" <fmt:message key=\"text.test\"/>"),
```

and

```
Option1(" ${option1}"),
```

with

```
<fmt:message key="text.select" var="option1"/>
```

in the .jsp.
Neither of them work, so it seems it can't work this way. What is the correct way of translating the strings? Ideally using the fmt:message and i18n resources (lang.properties files) that are in place and working on the rest of the servlet?

Answer (score 6):

Optimally, you get the resource key from the enum, and look that up.

```
public enum CheckboxFeature {
    Option1("label.option1.key"),
    Option2("label.option2.key"),
    Option1("label.option3.key"),
    Option2("label.option4.key");

    private final String key;
    [...]
```

I don't know how to nest a l10n lookup in the `itemLabel` attribute, so I would write something like:

```
<c:forEach items="Options.values()" var="current">
    <form:checkbox path="selectedOptions" value="${current.name()}"/> <fmt:message key="${current.getKey()}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

1、CheckboxFeature add method like:

```
 public static List<String> getAllCheckboxFeature(String v) {
        return Arrays.asList(Option1.getText(),...Option4.getText());
 }
```

2、than use the jstl like:

```
<c:forEach items="${options}" var="option">
    <input type="checkbox" ="${option}">
</c:forEach>
```